# Making context-free grammar unambiguous

Tags: context-free, ambiguity

I'm trying to change below *context free grammar* such that it becomes unambiguous, but I don't know what steps I should take. Is there any specific way of doing that?

Here is my CFG:
\begin{align}
&S \to SS \mid T \\
&T \to aTb \mid ab
\end{align}

Comment: Step 1. Figure out what language is accepted by this grammar. Step 2. Write an unambiguous grammar from scratch.

Comment: In your case, you only need to change one of the rules of $S$.

Comment: thanks for your response, but what rule I need to change? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: I won't spell it out.

Comment: LOL ! why plz... @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Since this site is not a homework-answering service. If that's what you're looking for, try [math.se].

Comment: @Mohammad, in case you want to solve it by yourself, think about "ababab", why is this string ambiguous for your grammar? How can you fix the grammar in order to make such kinds of strings unambiguously generated?. If you want to find an answer online, just follow Step 1. of Yuval's comment, you'll realize that your problem is very standard, and there are many solutions online. Your professor probably ust wanted to disguise a classical example.